# How to fetch data from api and initialize in autocomplete in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `Autocomplete` in flutter and data in `Autocomplete` is fetched from api. The following is my code:

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < _data.length; i++)
  Container(
    child: Autocomplete<CourseModels>(
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue value) {
        return _data[i]
            .courses
            .where(
              (element) => element.name
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(value.text.toLowerCase()),
            )
            .toList();
      },
      displayStringForOption: (CourseModels e) => '${e.name}',
      onSelected: (CourseModels selectedTag) {
        selectedTag.name;
        _userCompanyId = selectedTag.id;
        print(selectedTag.id);
      },
      fieldViewBuilder: (
        context, 
        _controller, 
        focusNode, 
        onEditiingComplete,
      ) {
        return Textfields(
          onChanged: (String value) {
            _userCompanyName = value;
          },
          onSaved: (input) => _userCompanyName = input,
          controller: _controller,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          iconSuffix: Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
          iconSize: 30,
          iconColor: Colors.black54,
          hintText: 'Select or Create company name',
          hintStyle: GoogleFonts.inter(
            color: Colors.black54,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
```

The output is like this:

[image]

Instead of having multiple `Autocomplete` options, it has multiple `Container` itself. The problem is from this code `for (int i = 0; i < _data.length; i++)` being on top of `Container` but when I try to put it inside `Autocomplete` it shows error. What should I do?